# Touchable Highlight not rendering image

Tags: react-native, expo

So I've added a TouchableHighlight into my code but it doesn't render the image into the app, and the navigation prop assigned to it isn't activated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Center } from "@builderx/utils";
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Text } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { MainNavigation } from '../screens/MainNavigator';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'
import { AppContainer } from "../screens/MainNavigator"

export default class DlLoading_2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <Center />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => 
{this.props.navigation.navigate('DlMain')}}>
          <Image
          source={require('../assets/ComponentTMP_0-image.jpg')}
          style={styles.blueDisk}/>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Center horizontal> 
          <Image
            source={require("../assets/ComponentTMP_0-image2.png")}
            style={styles.dlLogo}
          />
        </Center> 
        <Center horizontal>
          <Text style={styles.text}>TRANSINDENTAL MEDITATION</Text>
        </Center>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  blueDisk: {
    height: 401.5,
    width: 602,
    position: "absolute"
    }
});
```

I've tried changing the image type, adding the styling to the  element and that's pretty much all I can think of.

Comment: I think `position:absolute` removed would display the image.

Comment: it does man, thank you! but the image isn't centred anymore...

Comment: try wrapping it inside a view. Or play around with `resizeMethod`